# How to add ActionEvent to Two JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, actionevent

Question is: How do i add code to ensure that a table number (tableNumberJTextField) and waiter name (waiterNameJTextField) have been entered? If one or all fields are empty Use a JOptionPane to inform user that both fields must contain Information

At the moment i have:

```
private void calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed( 
      ActionEvent event )

{

    if(event.getSource() == tableNumberJTextField)   
     {

     }
     else
     {
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Information missing");
     }

   } // end method calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed
```

Would i need another IF...Else and a JOptionPane in there for WaiterName as well as tableNumberJTextField seen in the code above OR am i completely doing this wrong????

FULL QUESTION THAT I HAVE TO DO IS:
calculateBillJButtonActionPerformed method (which immediately follows dessertJComboBoxItemStateChanged) and add code to ensure that a table number (tableNumberJTextField) and waiter name (waiterNameJTextField) have been entered. If one of these fields is empty, display a JOptionPane informing the user that both fields must contain information. Otherwise, call the calculateSubtotal method, which you implement in the next step, to calculate the subtotal of the bill. The calculateSubtotal method takes no arguments and returns a double containing the subtotal, which you should display in subtotalJTextField. Calculate and display the tax and the total of the bill in JTextFields taxJTextField and totalJTextField, respectively. The tax rate is specified in a constant TAX_RATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the actionPerformed you're showing is for a button.  If so, just check for text in the fields:

```
   String tableNumber = tableNumberJTextField.getText().trim();
   String waiterName = waiterNameJTextField.getText().trim();

   if (tableNumber.length() == 0 || waiterName.length() == 0)
    {
       // show an error
    }
    else
    {
       // do a calculation
    }
```

Comment: Okay basically I have a Calculate Bill button, If tableNumberTextField and WaiterNameTextField have nothing in them when i hit this button to Calculate, I am to provide JOptionPane message saying that either or both fields have nothing in them. How would i do that?

Comment: Well, I just showed you the logic portion. If you want to learn about showing dialogs, read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: No i think i get what you're saying here, the do a Calculation in the ELSE part of the code, that would refer to the rest of the question i posted.... i.e Otherwise call the calculateSubtotal method???

Comment: Presumably yes (but you didn't show your code for that method, so I'm just guessing).

Comment: Well i will post the next method to that in an answer to my first question, could you venture a guess because i am quite stuck with this, thanks

Comment: Well, I answered your original question about validating that 2 text fields are populated on a button click. If it answered THAT question, then mark it as correct.  If not, then I can explain further. If you have an additional questions about your project, I would suggest starting a new question, that has a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the specific problem you're having.

Comment: Okay well i have marked it correct, okay what i will do i ill start a new question but with the whole question from my first question plus the added bit i want answered also, Code will be provided.